# How to model observation error of multiple entries on a single Likert-type item?

Tags: survey, likert, measurement-error

This is a hypothetical problem for me at the moment because (1) I have no such data and (2) often software provides a forced choice in these cases so I doubt it would be a problem if I conducted a survey with modern tools. But it is an interesting observational error to me.

Suppose we have a [Likert-type item](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likert_scale) on a survey. A participant pencils in two numbers on the same item. For example, on a scale $[1,5]$ the participant circles both 4 and 5 and there is no indication of which answer would have been preferred by the participant. And suppose this issue isn't detected until after the participant is long-gone.

Suppose we are predicting this response level using an [ordered logit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logit) based on some other attributes of the participant. This is likely what I would consider on a real problem.

Should I treat these two numbers as repeated measurements by the same participant? Or do something else with it?

Answer (score 2):

It's not repeated measures. This isn't multiple measures from one person.

If there is relatively little of this (which seems likely) then it won't make much difference what you do and I might simply say "when two adjacent numbers are chosen, we will use the lower one".

If you want something more sophisticated, I would look into multiple imputation, but limit it to the two numbers that were chosen, and use other variables to make the imputation sets. Software such as R or SAS will be able to do this without TOO much trouble.